# How can I have my content fill in the remainder of the page when I'm using Material UI AppBar?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using **React** and **Material UI React** for my application. I want the site to utilize the `AppBar` component with content below, but I don't want the content to cause scrolling on the entire page; I want my content to take up the maximum remaining height and the page width.

**Layout.tsx**:

```
<AppBar position="static" component="header">
  <Toolbar>
    <Logo className={classes.logo} />
    <div className={classes.grow} />
    <IconButton className={classes.avatar} edge="end">
      <Avatar />
    </IconButton>
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
<Container className={classes.content} component="main">
  {props.children}
</Container>
```

I've been trying different combinations of the available `position` for the `AppBar`, which are `"static" | "fixed" | "absolute" | "sticky" | "relative" | undefined`, along with different heights and widths for the content, but no combination seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try MUI's scroller hook to anchor the bar: https://next.material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#elevate-app-bar, or constraint the container to the window like I did with your code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-full-page-no-scroll-whecl?file=/demo.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sx={{maxHeight: 20vh for appBar and 80vh for the content}}

```
<AppBar position="static" component="header" sx={{maxHeight:20vh}}>
  <Toolbar>
    <Logo className={classes.logo} />
    <div className={classes.grow} />
    <IconButton className={classes.avatar} edge="end">
      <Avatar />
    </IconButton>
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
<Container className={classes.content} component="main" sx={{maxHeight:80vh}}>
  {props.children}
</Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

here what mui says:
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/#fixed-placement

basically you have to use fake Toolbar in your container.
Somehow like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

export function Home() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: "98vh" }}>
      <AppBar component="nav">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            component="div"
            sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' } }}
          >MUI</Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Toolbar/>
      <Box component="main" sx={{ height: 'calc(100% - 56px)', backgroundColor:'red' }}>      
         <Typography sx={{ height: '100%' }}>Something in the Way</Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```